# What does `rospy.wait_for_message('/scan', LaserScan)` mean?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new in ROS melodic of Ubuntu 18.04.

As far as I know, the only way to get some topic is to declare `rospy.Subscribe`.

However, I've seen

```
data = rospy.wait_for_message('/scan', LaserScan, timeout=5)
```

According to [here](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html), `rospy.wait_for_message` receives one message from topic.

And I really have no idea how different between `rospy.Subscribe` and `rospy.wait_for_message`.

If anyone who is familiar with this, would you please give me some  advice?

Thanks in advance. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345674/what-does-%60rospy.wait_for_message(%27/scan%27,-laserscan)%60-mean?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> And I really have no idea how different between `rospy.Subscribe` and `rospy.wait_for_message`.

The difference is this:

`rospy.Subscriber` is a Python class which encapsulates a subscription to a topic. You create an instance of this class whenever you use `rospy.Subscriber("<topic_name>", <topic_type>, <callback>)`. Provided something publishes to `<topic_name>`, the callback registered will be invoked for *every message received*.

`rospy.wait_for_message(..)` is a convenience function, which, as you wrote yourself: "receives one message from [a] topic" and then returns.

More precisely (and a copy of the documentation):

> This will create a new subscription to the topic, receive one message, then unsubscribe.

So this function (in pseudo-code almost):

1. creates a `rospy.Subscriber`
2. initialises a flag to `False`
3. waits for a single message, which
4. triggers its callback to be called
5. this callback sets the flag to `True`
6. the `True` flag will cause the function to cancel its subscription, and
7. it now returns the message it has received

You could do all of this yourself, but it's much more convenient to have `rospy.wait_for_message(..)` do this for you.

Note: what you should **not** do is use `wait_for_message(..)` to "sample" a topic, like so:

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    msg = rospy.wait_for_message(..)
    ...
```

this is very inefficient and almost an anti-pattern.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-03-03**:
Thanks for the quick reply. So, you recommended I not using `wait_for_message(..)` to just sample a topic, and when would you advise me to consider select that? I've planned to use it right just

```
data = rospy.wait_for_message('/scan', LaserScan, timeout=5)
```

as you wrote. Would you please tell me when is the most appropriate time to use `rospy.wait_for_message`?  Thanks :)

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-06**:\

> when would you advise me to consider select that

If you need to receive the data from a topic only once (like maybe a topic publishing a configuration or info about something that isn't changing during the execution) then it's fine to use `wait_for_message`.

Your example is about the `/scan` topic, which is a topic that is published by your sensor very frequently (generally speaking) so unless you just need your sensor data once (which is odd) you would want to have a permanent subscriber to the `/scan` topic to always get the latest sensor informations.